# login(request, user) not working in python django

Tags: python, django, authentication

*This is my page url within the `urls.py` file:*

```
path('login/',views.login_view, name="login"),
```

*This is my page view with the `views.py` file:*

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.POST.get("username")
        pass_word = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=user_name, password=pass_word)
        # print("user1 -->", user)

        if user is not None:
            # print("user-->",user)
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "index.html")
        else:
            return render(request,"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login")
    else:
        # return render(request, "order.html")
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

*The error I am getting is:*

> TypeError at /login/logincheck/login() missing 1 required positional
> argument: 'user'

Comment: What's the name of view you're using?

Comment: Show your import and full view.

Comment: *from multiprocessing import context
import django
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from datetime import datetime
from home.forms import NewUserForm
from home.models import Contact
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
from . import forms
from .models import Product
from math import ceil*

Comment: I am using login_view

Answer (score 0):

first create a `forms.py` file:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=63)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=63, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

your `views.py` should seem like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from . import forms

def login_view(request):
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
            )
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                message = f'Hello {user.username}! You have been logged in'
            else:
                message = 'Login failed!'
    return render(
        request, 'authentication/login.html', context={'form': form, 'message': message})
```

Comment: I tried but i am getting error *TypeError at /login/logincheck/
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'*

Comment: @AshishSarraf share your view with its name and also your whole  urls.py

Comment: i post my project on github here is the link : https://github.com/Ashishkumar5699/Ecommerce-College-Project

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @enes islam's approach... It's okay with what he posted as his answer but according to your project you have another view in your `views.py` file called `login` so maybe it's using that view and not the `django` `login` method you imported.

```
# You have this import line here    
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login


# But I noticed further down you have a defined login method

def login(request):  # -> rename this method name to loginDjano or another name.
     return render(request, "login.html")
```

That defined method is what is really being called here... So I'd suggest you delete or rename that method then go ahead and use that line again.

```
if user is not None:
     # Remember to pass both request and user objects to this login method
     login(request, user)

     message = f'Hello {user.username}! You have been logged in'
else:
     message = 'Login failed!'
```

Ideally, that should work.

Comment: yes when I am trying login(request , user) method I am getting error login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: @AshishSarraf it seems you have not renamed your custom method as encouraged. Hence, the program is still calling your custom `login` method it seems. Have you renamed your custom `login` method to another name?

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your problem though, you should probably accept this as the answer to your question to help others who might have the same issue in the future. :-)